# How to decrease vetical distance between two checkboxes with label?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I used Material-UI for the checkboxes. The default checkbox seems to have a large size for the 'input' tag which is used internally (found after exploring DevTools). I don't seem to find any way to target the 'input' element to resize it to my need. I tried using a negative margin and that' works but I am not satisfied with that. How do I target the 'input' element to resize it according to my need? Here is the code and screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the UI]

```js
import React from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

import CheckboxWithLabel from "../checkbox-with-label/checkbox-with-label";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  filterContainer: {
    width: 218,
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  item: {
    height: 20,
  },
});

const FilterList = (props) => {
  const { label } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Paper elevation={0} className={classes.filterContainer}>
      <Grid container direction="column">
        <Grid item>
          <CheckboxWithLabel label={label} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <CheckboxWithLabel label={label} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <CheckboxWithLabel label={label} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default FilterList;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox as MUICheckbox } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    height: 20,
  },
});

const Checkbox = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <MUICheckbox color="primary" classes={{ input: classes.input }} />;
};

export default Checkbox;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  label: {
    fontSize: "0.9rem",
  },
});

const CheckboxWthLabel = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { label } = props;
  const handleChange = () => {
    setState(!state);
  };
  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      classes={{ label: classes.label }}
      control={
        <Checkbox onChange={handleChange} color="primary" size="small" />
      }
      label={label}
    />
  );
};

export default CheckboxWthLabel;
```

And here is what it looks like in DevTools

```html
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-direction-xs-column">
   <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item">
      <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
         <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root PrivateSwitchBase-root-208 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary PrivateSwitchBase-checked-209 Mui-checked MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
               <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-211" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
               <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeSmall" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
               </svg>
            </span>
            <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
         </span>
         <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label makeStyles-label-207 MuiTypography-body1">Daraz</span>
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item">
      <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
         <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root PrivateSwitchBase-root-208 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
               <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-211" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
               <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeSmall" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
               </svg>
            </span>
            <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
         </span>
         <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label makeStyles-label-207 MuiTypography-body1">Daraz</span>
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item">
      <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root">
         <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root PrivateSwitchBase-root-208 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary PrivateSwitchBase-checked-209 Mui-checked MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
               <input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-211" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
               <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeSmall" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
               </svg>
            </span>
            <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
         </span>
         <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label makeStyles-label-207 MuiTypography-body1">Daraz</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you include some reproducible code of the actual layout in the image your provided?

Comment: I have edited the post to include all the related code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the rule name of `root` instead of `input` (I don't think `input` rule name is in the docs for MUI Checkbox). Here on `root`, you can use `box-sizing: border-box` so that the padding will also be considered in the computation for its `height`. Regarding the inner `input` you have mentioned, it has the CSS property `height: 100%` so it should respond.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    height: "20px",
    boxSizing: "border-box" // <-- add this
  }
});

const Checkbox = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <MUICheckbox color="primary" classes={{ root: classes.input }} />;
};

export default Checkbox;
```

[image: Edit nice-lalande-cx54h]

Comment: The code works quite well in the sandbox and works locally if I replicate it exactly. But if I tried to put the logic in a separate file for "separation of concern" it does not work. Why is it so? I tried to keep the logic in three files so they are components as in the post.

Comment: Oh, i got it. Instead of importing Checkbox from my local file, I seem to have been importing it from @material-ui/core. Thanks for the answer.